# How can I create a file with interface names in specific parts and later parsed from an another file to modify the interface with data in GO?

Tags: go

I am building a program to change IP address of the machine in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. So basically I am creating a YAML file template with

```
network:
   ethernets:
      {INTERFACE}:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses: [{IP}/24]
          gateway4: {GATEWAY}
          optional: true
          nameservers:
           addresses: [{DNS}]
     {INTERFACE2}:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses: [{IP2}/24]
          gateway4: {GATEWAY2}
          optional: true
          nameservers:
           addresses: [{DNS2}]
```

Now I need to scan this template file and add the values from an another file either through a JSON call or as parameters in CLI.

So the app will take a template file that has been pre-prepared. Such as the example template for yaml file.

It will take 3 parameters
this template file, a translation file(JSON), and the output

the translation file could be parsed on the commandline also

It is based on 2 columns, the search variable such as IP and its new value
The utility will search for the `{IP}` variable and replace it with the second column value.

On the CLI it might look like this:

> ./searchreplace -intemplate='templateip.yaml' -translation='{IP},xxx.x.x.x;
>   {SUBNET},yyy.yyy.yyy.y} -outfile=/tmp/newipfile.yaml

My current code hard codes the data and changes the IP but I want it to be in a separate template file. This is my current code

```
    package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

var pathdelete = "/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml"
var ipv4Regex = regexp.MustCompile(`^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]+$`)
var gatewayRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$`)
var nsRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`^(?:[0-9]\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\,(?:[0-9]\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$`)
var nicRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`e([a-z]+)`)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter the IP address: ")
    IPaddress, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    IPaddress = strings.TrimSuffix(IPaddress, "\n")

    //sanity check
    testInput := net.ParseIP(IPaddress)
    if testInput.To4() == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v is not a valid IPv4 address\n", testInput)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("It is a valid IP address\n")
        writeFile()
        readFile()
    }
}
func writeFile() {
    err01 := os.Truncate(pathdelete, 0)
    if err01 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err01)
    }

    //reading Network Cards
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter the Ethernet Card (for example : 'ens0N' or 'eth0') ")
    nic, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    nic = strings.TrimSuffix(nic, "\n")
    if nicRegex.MatchString(nic) {
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Please check the name of the NIC Card you have entered")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    //reading IP Address and DNS
    fmt.Print("Enter the IP address along with the DNS in the format xxx.xxx.x.xxx/yy ")
    IP, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    IP = strings.TrimSuffix(IP, "\n")

    if ipv4Regex.MatchString(IP) {
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Please check the IP address you have entered")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    //reading Gateway
    fmt.Print("Enter the gateway in the format xxx.xxx.x.x ")
    gateway, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    gateway = strings.TrimSuffix(gateway, "\n")
    if gatewayRegex.MatchString(gateway) {
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Please check the Gateway you have entered")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    //reading Name servers
    fmt.Print("Enter the nameservers seperated by comma(,) in the format x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y ")
    ns, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    ns = strings.TrimSuffix(ns, "\n")
    if nsRegex.MatchString(ns) {
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Please check the Name Servers you have entered")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // open file using READ & WRITE permission
    var file, err = os.OpenFile(pathdelete, os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    checkError(err)
    defer file.Close()

    // write some text to file
    _, err = file.WriteString("# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system\nnetwork:\n  version: 2\n  renderer: NetworkManager\n")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return //must return here for defer statements to be called
    }
    _, err = file.WriteString("  ethernets:\n    " + nic + ":\n      dhcp4: no\n      dhcp6: no\n")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return //same as above
    }
    _, err = file.WriteString("      addresses: [" + IP + "]\n      gateway4: " + gateway + "\n      nameservers:\n        addresses: [" + ns + "]")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return //same as above
    }

    // save changes
    err = file.Sync()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return //same as above
    }
    applyCmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "sudo netplan apply")
    _, err2 := applyCmd.Output()
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
}

func readFile() {
    // re-open file
    var file, err = os.OpenFile(pathdelete, os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    checkError(err)
    defer file.Close()

    // read file
    var text = make([]byte, 1024)
    n, err := file.Read(text)
    if n > 0 {
        fmt.Println("\nThe data you have entered is \n ")
        fmt.Println(string(text))
    }
    //if there is an error while reading
    //just print however much was read if any
    //at return file will be closed
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to change the IP by hardcoding the template file inside my main program.

Comment: You should take a look at text/template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to carry this out by converting the command line input

> ./program --xyz.yaml --{interface} eth0 --IPaddress 192.168.1.233/24 --{gateway} 192.168.0.1 --DNS 8.8.3.8,8.8.8.3

I used a mapping function to map the CLI to strings with this

```
func manyRandomArg() map[string]string {
    rv := make(map[string]string)
    for ix, x := range os.Args {
        if x[:2] == "--" {
            rv[x] = os.Args[ix+1]
        }
    }
    return rv
}
```

Then I sorted only the keys and carried out the Search Replace function

```
keys := make([]string, 0, len(rv))
    for key := range rv {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys) //sort keys alphabetically
```

Had to trim the '--' part in the key

```
key0 = trimLeftChars(keys[0], 2)
```

The string replace function used was

```
r := strings.NewReplacer(key0, rv[keys[0]], key1, rv[keys[1]], key2, rv[keys[2]], key3, rv[keys[3]], key4, rv[keys[4]])
```